# Lihaoyi PPrint Deep Tree

Tags: scala, pprint

---

title: Lihaoyi PPrint Deep Tree

### link: [Lihaoyi PPrint Deep Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675619/lihaoyi-pprint-deep-tree)

I have a "deep" tree of case classes that I want to pprint as "like Scala" source code.

> ... because I want to view, copy and paste them to make a UnitTest

I am using [lihaoyi's pprint](http://www.lihaoyi.com/upickle-pprint/pprint/) to perform the `stringify` of the values, BUT **after a few levels, pprint stops** printing.
I've checked in the `tokenize` thing and the instance is being emitted as-is; you can see that the strings aren't being excaped.

I can (manually) "tweak" my tests to test parts of the results and get my pretty source, but ... it feels wrong.

### Original "Lack of deep" printout

```
Module(
    Set(),
    Set(
        Material(
            "testTextLayoutContainer",
            List(
                Attribute("Position", VecSingle(2)),
                Attribute("UV", VecSingle(2)),
                Attribute("Color", VecFixed(4))
            ),
            List(
                UniformInstance("ProjMtx", MatSingle(4, 4)),
                UniformInstance("Texture", Texture(2, VecFixed(4)))
            ),
            Set(
                //
                // this is the line that's not being pprinted
                //

                Program(ImGui,testTextLayoutContainer,Set(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4)), Attribute(Position,VecSingle(2)), Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))),Set(UniformInstance(Texture,Texture(2,VecFixed(4))), UniformInstance(ProjMtx,MatSingle(4,4))),Set(VaryingCopy(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4))), VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2)))),List(Lookup(UniformInstance(ProjMtx,MatSingle(4,4))), Lookup(Attribute(Position,VecSingle(2))), Literal(0.0), Literal(1.0), Construct(VecSingle(4),List(Lookup(Attribute(Position,VecSingle(2))), Literal(0.0), Literal(1.0))), External(mat*vec,List(Lookup(UniformInstance(ProjMtx,MatSingle(4,4))), Construct(VecSingle(4),List(Lookup(Attribute(Position,VecSingle(2))), Literal(0.0), Literal(1.0)))),VecSingle(4)), Output(Vertex(ProductTransform(Lookup(UniformInstance(ProjMtx,MatSingle(4,4))),Construct(VecSingle(4),List(Lookup(Attribute(Position,VecSingle(2))), Literal(0.0), Literal(1.0))))),External(mat*vec,List(Lookup(UniformInstance(ProjMtx,MatSingle(4,4))), Construct(VecSingle(4),List(Lookup(Attribute(Position,VecSingle(2))), Literal(0.0), Literal(1.0)))),VecSingle(4))), Lookup(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4))), Output(VaryingCopy(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4))),Lookup(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4)))), Lookup(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))), Output(VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))),Lookup(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))))),List(Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4)))), Access(Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4)))),x), Lookup(UniformInstance(Texture,Texture(2,VecFixed(4)))), Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2)))), Sample(UniformInstance(Texture,Texture(2,VecFixed(4))),Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))))), Access(Sample(UniformInstance(Texture,Texture(2,VecFixed(4))),Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))))),x), External(*,List(Access(Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4)))),x), Access(Sample(UniformInstance(Texture,Texture(2,VecFixed(4))),Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))))),x)),VecFixed(1)), Access(Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4)))),y), Access(Sample(UniformInstance(Texture,Texture(2,VecFixed(4))),Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))))),y), External(*,List(Access(Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4)))),y), Access(Sample(UniformInstance(Texture,Texture(2,VecFixed(4))),Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))))),y)),VecFixed(1)), Access(Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4)))),z), Access(Sample(UniformInstance(Texture,Texture(2,VecFixed(4))),Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))))),z), External(*,List(Access(Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4)))),z), Access(Sample(UniformInstance(Texture,Texture(2,VecFixed(4))),Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))))),z)),VecFixed(1)), Access(Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4)))),w), Access(Sample(UniformInstance(Texture,Texture(2,VecFixed(4))),Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))))),w), External(*,List(Access(Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4)))),w), Access(Sample(UniformInstance(Texture,Texture(2,VecFixed(4))),Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))))),w)),VecFixed(1)), Construct(VecFixed(4),List(External(*,List(Access(Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4)))),x), Access(Sample(UniformInstance(Texture,Texture(2,VecFixed(4))),Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))))),x)),VecFixed(1)), External(*,List(Access(Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4)))),y), Access(Sample(UniformInstance(Texture,Texture(2,VecFixed(4))),Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))))),y)),VecFixed(1)), External(*,List(Access(Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4)))),z), Access(Sample(UniformInstance(Texture,Texture(2,VecFixed(4))),Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))))),z)),VecFixed(1)), External(*,List(Access(Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4)))),w), Access(Sample(UniformInstance(Texture,Texture(2,VecFixed(4))),Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))))),w)),VecFixed(1)))), Output(Fragment(Construct(VecFixed(4),List(ProductAtomic(Access(Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4)))),x),Access(Sample(UniformInstance(Texture,Texture(2,VecFixed(4))),Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))))),x)), ProductAtomic(Access(Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4)))),y),Access(Sample(UniformInstance(Texture,Texture(2,VecFixed(4))),Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))))),y)), ProductAtomic(Access(Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4)))),z),Access(Sample(UniformInstance(Texture,Texture(2,VecFixed(4))),Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))))),z)), ProductAtomic(Access(Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4)))),w),Access(Sample(UniformInstance(Texture,Texture(2,VecFixed(4))),Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))))),w))))),Construct(VecFixed(4),List(External(*,List(Access(Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4)))),x), Access(Sample(UniformInstance(Texture,Texture(2,VecFixed(4))),Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))))),x)),VecFixed(1)), External(*,List(Access(Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4)))),y), Access(Sample(UniformInstance(Texture,Texture(2,VecFixed(4))),Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))))),y)),VecFixed(1)), External(*,List(Access(Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4)))),z), Access(Sample(UniformInstance(Texture,Texture(2,VecFixed(4))),Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))))),z)),VecFixed(1)), External(*,List(Access(Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(Color,VecFixed(4)))),w), Access(Sample(UniformInstance(Texture,Texture(2,VecFixed(4))),Lookup(VaryingCopy(Attribute(UV,VecSingle(2))))),w)),VecFixed(1)))))))
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a height and a width, so if you provide a big enough value it will show it all.

```
scala> pprint.pprintln(Seq(1, 2, 3), width = Int.MaxValue, height = Int.MaxValue)
```

so

```
@ pprint.pprintln(1 to 10, 3, 10) 
Range.Inclusive(
  1,
  2...
```

can be

```
@ pprint.pprintln(1 to 10, Int.MaxValue, Int.MaxValue) 
Range.Inclusive(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Edit:

as mentioned in the docs this is a feature to stop out of memory errors when printing really big data structures.

http://www.lihaoyi.com/upickle-pprint/pprint/#GettingStarted